# Term for urban planning?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-request, architecture

So while there is a plethora of words regarding features of urban planning in Latin, is there an actual term or phrase for the act of planning a city? "Urbs designans" and "inventio urbica" seem like poor fits to me, and I feel like a culture with such a civil engineering bent would have had a dedicated word for the urban planning field, but I just can't find any.

In addition, within the field, was there a term for the city grid? I am aware of the terms for the various streets, buildings, etc., but "reticulum urbicum" strikes me as incorrect, as I was under the impression "reticulum" meant more of a "net" than a "grid," and "cancellus" seems to be more associated with literal bars than cities. Again, I find it hard to believe, given the nature of the Romans, that they would not have had a word for a city grid, but I simply can't seem to find it.

Comment: I like your question. You might like to consult a book called Ancient Rome: City Planning and Administration by Olivia F. Robinson. Her scholarly work comes up on searches of articles about aqueducts and other public works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vitruvius discusses some aspects of urban planning in the first book of his famous [*De architectura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_architectura).
However, I do not seem to find a term for "urban planning" there.
He discusses the topic but does not seem to give it a name.

This is the closest hit that I found:

> *arearum divisiones platearumque* ([Vitr. 1.6.1](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0072%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D6%3Asection%3D1))
>   the apportionment of house lots ([translation by Morris Hicky Morgan](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0073%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D6%3Asection%3D1))

If there is no good attested expression in the literature, you should consider coining a new one in classical style.
I would suggest *designatio urbis* or *urbs designanda*.
(*Urbs designans* implies that the city is the one that plans instead of the one being planned. An active participle sounds like a bad fit here.)

There might be something better, but it missed my eye.
At any rate, digging through *De architectura* is what I suggest doing first in the search for such a word.

There is probably something for a "city grid" too, but I found nothing better than *angiportorum divisiones*, "the directions of the different alleys" (1.6.13, see the two links above).
If I were to coin a new expression for it, I would probably choose *rete viarum*, "network of roads".

Comment: Reading through 1.6.12 gave me an interesting word: _vicus_. Apparently it technically means quarter, neighborhood, row of houses, municipal section, or ward, which, while not exactly the same thing, is certainly a bit more convenient than _angiportorum divisiones_. I think its close enough to use for grid, as it has the municipal nature missing from the words I listed in my question. Perhaps used exclusively in the plural, so as to refer to the collection of wards. Insofar as urban planning goes, I think your suggested _designatio urbis_ is suitable. Thanks for the source!

Comment: @James You are welcome! [*Vicus* (L&S link)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=vicus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is a good word, but it can mean a number of things. If there is a risk of confusion, something more concrete like *rete viarum* (road network) might be better.